# $L_1$ norm of Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability

Ok. This is bit confusing. Let $g$ be a Gaussian random variable (normalized, i.e. with mean 0 and standard deviation 1). Then, in the expression $$\|g\|_{L_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|\exp(\frac{-x^2}{2})dx =\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}},$$ shouldn't the term $|x|$ *not* appear in the integral?

Comment: The term $|x|$ will not be there in the integral if you were computing the $L_1$ norm of the _density function._ Here you are computing the $L_1$ norm of the _random variable._

Comment: Oh. I see. Silly me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable with density $f$, and $\phi$ is a measurable function, then $E[\phi(X)]=\int_{\Bbb R}\phi(t)f(t)dt$. As the $L^1$ norm of a random variable $X$ is $E[|X|]$, we have, when $X$ is normally distributed, the announced result.

Answer (score 2):

It should! The $L_1$-norm of a random variable $X$ with density $f(x)$ equals
$$\int_{\Omega} |X(w)| d\mu(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x| f(x) dx,$$
where $(\Omega, \mu)$ is the probability space $X$ defined on.