# Norm of convolution of $n$ Gaussians

Tags: fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, convolution

If

$$f(x)=e^{-(\pi x)^2}$$ and

$$\psi_n(x)=(f* f*\dots*f)(x)$$  ($n$ times convolution).

Show that

$$\lVert \psi_n(x)\rVert = 1$$ (norm in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$).

I've tried using the Fourier Transform property but I'm stuck!
Thanks

Comment: I think the correct notation is $(f * f * \cdots * f)(x)$.

Comment: No, sorry, i forgot to specify it. The Norm is L1(R)

Comment: @Tunococ yes, you're right, edited ;)

Comment: Does anything in this question help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240202/l-1-norm-of-gaussian-random-variable

Comment: I tried it, but the results i obtain is not 1, but is 1/sqrt(n) :(

Comment: Yes, I think I can see how you'd get that too, but then convolutions aren't my string point.....

Answer (score 1):

Taking the Fourier transform, $\hat{\psi}_n=\hat{f}\cdots\hat{f}$ with $n$ factors. We also [know](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html) that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian, in this case $\hat{f}(\xi)=e^{-(\pi\xi)^2}$. Therefore
$$\hat{\psi}_n(0)=\hat{f}(0)\cdots\hat{f}(0)=1^n=1.$$
Finally note $\hat{\psi}_n(0)=\int \psi_n(x)\;dx = \|\psi_n\|_1$ as the integrand is nonnegative.